# Is it possible to call EXECUTE AS OWNER later in object?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, impersonation, execute-as

Consider this code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterInsertUpdateTenant_Korisnici] 
ON [dbo].[Korisnici]
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
FOR INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @TenantId INT = dbo.GetCurrentTenantId();

    EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'sa';

    UPDATE Korisnici
    SET TenantId = @TenantId
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE Korisnici.Id = i.Id;

    REVERT;
```

On every table, there is a security policy that doesn't allow change of the `TenantId` column on the table other than the one that is bound to the database user, but the policy will allow it for the "sa" user.

Problem is `TenantId`, I need to get the `TenantId` with the calling principal because `TenantId` is bound to the database user. I know one solution: without `with execute` in a trigger and calling a procedure that has `with execute` after I get `TenantId` and pass it into a procedure, but then I'd have to copy table Inserted into temp table so that I can access it in the procedure.

I would like better a solution where I can call `execute as owner` later in object, after I get the `TenantId`. Logically it's valid, but the question is; have they implemented it? `execute as login = 'sa'` that you can see in the code is not a good solution because it requires that current login is able to impersonate the `sa` login.

Point of this trigger is to allow a user not to specify `TenantId` on an insert.
I don't have to even mention `TenantId` in the application, everything is only on the SQL Server.

Another solution would be if the creator of an object could write some info on an object that I could read in security policy and based on that info allow the user to update the `TenantId`. It may even be permissions on the object but the question is how can I read which object caused the call of the security policy?

Comment: you might have an XY problem....If your permissions are set up correctly I fail to see why you would even need to attempt such a thing...

Comment: I might, but I don't have any other solution if I want to use multitenancy and have a secure system. To have flexibility, security, and simplicity of maintenance. With this system, I may or may not have multiple tenants per database.

Comment: if it's multi-tenanted, place a service in front of the database....

Comment: It's a desktop app and creating a service is cumbersome and long lasting task. I am not creating it from scratch, just upgrading it.

Comment: ...unfortunately, it's also the 'correct' way to architect your solution. Another possibility, (and I stress I probably wouldn't do it this way) is to create a stored proc or function that is called at start of all entry points to DB, that checks client permissions....

Comment: How would service help, isn't an SQL Server just like a service? I have everything figured out and working, just this little detail is left. What would I get with the service?

Comment: The service layer would take care of enforcing security. " I have everything figured out and working" - clearly not!

Comment: "clearly not! " please read the question where I have stated that I have a solution but I would like a better one if it's possible. For me procedure for every entry to database is not a good choice, why then all those option that server has, like security policy...

Comment: Procedures as entry into the db would disable the use of EF querying, I'd like to have it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution where trigger calls the procedure that is in the schema forbidden to a user. The trigger has no "with execute" and can get TenantId and forward that info to the procedure. In the procedure, I have "with execute as owner" and is able to change records regarding any Tenant. Also, I am copying needed columns of the Inserted table into the temp table so that the procedure can see it, I don't see a way around that.

Even better solution:

```
alter trigger [dbo].[AfterInsertUpdateTenant_Korisnici]
on [dbo].[Korisnici]
with execute as owner
for insert 
as 
execute as user = original_login();
declare @TenantId int = dbo.GetCurrentTenantId();
revert;

update dbo.Korisnici
set TenantId = @TenantId
from Inserted i
where dbo.Korisnici.Id = i.Id;
```